# PrestaShop Переадресация админки

Tags: cms, prestashop

Вчера поставил Prestashop 1.6, накатил шаблон, все было ок.
Сегодня не могу зайти в админку, админка переадресовывается  на сайт. Сайт работает.
Что делать?

Comment: включить Debug как минимум, + проверить правельность написания ссылки до админки

Comment: Уверен, что написано правильно, т.к. установил цмс не вручную, а по средствам хостинга.
Как включить debug?

Answer (score 0):

как включить debug mode без админки: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/575132-how-to-enable-debug-mode-on-prestashop-17-and-older-versions-turn-on-error-reporting-blank-page/

еще можно попробовать отключить файл `.htaccess` в папке админ-панели, может это из-за него выбрасывает.